# How to break RSA signature on XOR of hashed blocks

Tags: rsa, signature, xor

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way of breaking or weakening the following method of signing long messages

Given $M=m_{1}m_{2}...m_{n},\,\,|m_i|=64b,
\,\,h=h(m_{1})\oplus h(m_{2})\oplus\cdots\oplus h(m_{n})$

sign $h$ using the RSA method.

also, is it weaker than the original way (of signing every message separately)?

Comment: Can I ask what is the aim?

Comment: the general idea is to sign long messages with minimum signature length instead of signing every block

Comment: Is this homework? It looks like it. Please let us know so that we can answer appropriately.

Comment: It's not homework, it's a question from past exam, this is my first question here and I was wondering if I need to mention it, why is it important?

Comment: While possibly reducing the signature size, one has to process all to verify the sign for a single message.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that the calculation time will be about the same, what about the security of the method? I there a way I can forgery messages and sign them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sign a message $M = m_1 \ldots m_n$, you calculate $h(M) = h(m_1) \oplus \ldots \oplus h(m_n)$ then $S(M) = \textsf{RSASSA}(h(M))$ where $\textsf{RSASSA}$ is some RSA-based signature mechanism. $h$ is presumably a cryptographic hash function. You're looking for a weakness of this signing method.

Start small. Given $M = m_1 m_2$, can you think of another message $M'$ such that $S(M) = S(M')$? (Note that a weakness could be more complicated than this. For example, it could be impossible to find two messages with the same signature, but possible to derive the signature of $M'$ from the signature of $M$. However, in this case, it is possible to forge another message with the same signature.)

> $S(m_1 m_2) = \textsf{RSASSA}(h(m_1) \oplus h(m_2)) = \textsf{RSASSA}(h(m_2) \oplus h(m_1)) = S(m_2 m_1)$

Follow-up exercise (easy): given an arbitrary message $M = m_1 \ldots m_n$, find a longer message with the same signature. Hint:

> Above I used the fact that $\oplus$ is commutative. What other algebraic properties does $\oplus$ have?

The normal way to sign a message $m_1 \ldots m_n$ is of course $\textsf{RSASSA}(h(m_1 \ldots m_n))$. If you also want to be able to verify the signature of one part independently, one solution is to build a [hash tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) and sign the root hash. A two-level hash tree would be $h(h(m_1) \ldots h(m_n))$. If you transmit the signature $\textsf{RSASSA}(h(h(m_1) \ldots h(m_n)))$ as well as the list of individual hashes $(h(m_1), \ldots, h(m_n))$ then it's possible to verify the signature of any of the individual $m_i$. Signatures are larger than hashes and more expensive to compute, so this can save resources compared so signing each $m_i$ independently.